# Take a screenshot with VLC in debian CLI

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player

I have a peerflix stream on my linux machine which I want to open with VLC, take several screenshots at pre defined sections and save them to disk.

I managed to get this to work on windows using the documentation but I can't seem to get it to work on linux.

Sidenote: My video stream can be directly opened through an url like this `http://10.0.2.15:8888`

Comment: And you want to do this from the command line? Do you want to automate it? Can't you use the GUI? Would you be open to other tools like `mplayer`?

Comment: @terdon It's a headless machine and needs to be automated. So I can't just go and open a gui :). I'm fine with any tool as long as it can open a network stream such as peerflix's stream and can produce multiple screenshots at specific points